# injective functions require functions whose composition equal the identity function

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove:
Let $A, B$ be sets and let $f : A\to B $ be a function.
Prove that if $f$ is one to one then there is a function $g : B\to A$ so that $g(f)=id_A$

Here is what I have,

Suppose $f : A\to B $ is one to one, thus for any $x, y \in A$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$.
Now suppose for a contradiction that any  $g : B\to A$ is such that $g(f) \neq id_A$

That is, $g(f)= \left \{ (a,a) \in A\times A:[\exists b \in B:f(a)=b \wedge  g(b)=a]\right \}$
does not equal

$id_A= \left \{(a,a) \in A\times A: a \in A\right \}$.

However, one can see that $g(f) = id_A$ and thus a contradiction. Therefore if $f$ is one to one then there is a function  $g : B\to A$ such that $g(f)=id_A$

I get the feeling this may be wrong but I am unsure why, I think $g(f)=id_A$ but im not sure if the condition inside the set $g(f)$ simplifies to $a \in A$ also I didnt use the original hypothesis at all so Im wondering if that makes this proof not valid.

Where did I go wrong? Did I go wrong?

Comment: This requires $A\neq\emptyset$ or $A=B=\emptyset$, in which case $f=\mathrm{id}_A$ anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes started after you supposed that for every $g : B\to A$, $g(f) \neq id_A$. Your descriptions for $g(f)$ and $id_A$ are incorrect. The composition $g(f)$ is the function from $A$ into $A$ that maps $a\in A$ to $g(f(a))$; the identity $id_A$ is the function from $A$ into $A$ given by $id_A(a) = a$.

I would suggest arguing directly. Fix $x \in A$ and give a rule of assignment $g : B \to A$ by setting $g(b) = a$ if $b\in f(A)$ and $f(a) = b$, and $g(b) = x$ if $b\notin f(A)$. Since $f$ is $1-1$, each $b\in f(A)$ maps to a unique element of $A$. Indeed, if $b_1, b_2\in f(A)$, say $b_1 = f(a_1)$, $b_2 = f(a_2)$, and $b_1 = b_2$, then $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ $\implies$ $a_1 = a_2$ since $f$ is $1-1$. So $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$. It follows that $g$ is well-defined as a function from $B$ into $A$. Furthermore, by definition of $g$, $g(f(a)) = a$ for all $a\in A$, i.e., $g(f) = id_A$.

Comment: hmm I am fairly certain my function function definitions are correct, (I have compared them to those given in the text I am using) but I think I need to formally prove that $g(f) = id_A$ and then my proof is complete.

Comment: The set $A\times A$ consists of more than just those elements $(a,a)\in A\times A$ where $a\in A$. It would be acceptable to say $$g(f) = \{(a_1,a_2)\in A\times A : [\exists b\in B : f(a_1) = b \wedge g(b) = a_2]\}$$ and $$id_A = \{(a_1,a_2)\in A\times A : a_1 = a_2\}$$

Comment: very good point, was I correct in saying that "suppose that for every $g:B→A$, $g(f)≠id_A$" as a valid proof step? regardless of whether that would lead me anywhere, I want to know if it made sense to talk about any $g:B→A$? that is, did I negate the consequent correctly? and had I been able to draw out the conclusion I was going for (the negation of  $g(f)≠id_A$) would that have been a correct proof? I think it would have been a so called "trivial proof" but I just want to make sure im understanding the process better. If you need me to clarify, dont hesitate to ask

Comment: Yes, you made the correct negation, which is why I didn't comment on that.